# Keyboard is immediately hidden when focus TextField in LazyVStack (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, lazyvstack

I have a stack of cards, each card having a `TextField`, when focus a text field positioned at the bottom of the screen (on the area where the keyboard will appear) the card disappears, thus the keyboard disappears as well.
I expect that the field is focused and scrolled automatically to the visible area.
I found that the "Submit" button I have fixed at the bottom of the screen is causing the issue, so it works fine if I remove it.
Another solution would be to use `VStack` instead of `LazyVStack` but I really need this Lazy behaviour since there can be lots of cards

```
struct ContentView: View {

   @State private var text: String = ""

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           ScrollView {
               LazyVStack {
                   ForEach(0..<200, id: \.self) { _ in
                       CardView()
                   }
               }
           }
           Button("Submit") { }
               .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
               .background(Color.white)
            
       }.background(Color.secondary)
   }
}

struct CardView: View {

   @State private var text: String = ""

   var body: some View {
       TextField("text", text: $text)
           .frame(height: 50, alignment: .leading)
           .background(Color.white)
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably yet another SwiftUI bug when using `LazyVStack` in a `ScrollView`.
 Works well without the `LazyVStack`.
 See also:
 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66523786/swiftui-putting-a-lazyvstack-or-lazyhstack-in-a-scrollview-causes-stuttering-a

Comment: IMHO, a text field within a row in a table view doesn't seem like the best solution anyway. ;)  You may consider to show a detail view and pull up a modal when the user wants to edit something.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the button inside the section footer and make the footer pinned like this:

```swift
var body: some View {
   ScrollView {
       LazyVStack(pinnedViews: .sectionFooters) {
           Section {
               ForEach(0..<200, id: \.self) { _ in
                   CardView()
               }
           } footer: {
              Button("Submit") { }
                  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                  .background(Color.white)
           }
       }
   }
   .background(Color.secondary)
}
```

It seems to solve the issue with the disappearing keyboard (at least in the iOS 17.4 simulator), but introduces another problem where the scroll position of the focused text field gets calculated incorrectly and it gets overlapped by the footer. Not sure if it's helpful, but may be you can take it from here.

Comment: I get the same behaviour with the button as overlay and some padding on the content to push it above the button, however the focused field remains hidden under the button when keyboard is shown :(